# Requesting permissions after Android 6.0, API 23

Tags: android, android-permissions

How do I request permissions after Android 6.0 (API 23)? I don't want to ask it during runtime, i want to have the permission beforehand.

Comment: set targetSdkVersion 22

Comment: Is that a question ?Answer is  if you targeting 23 or above then you have to follow the permission model .

Comment: `permission API in > 23 (without run-time request)` **I M P O S S I B L E**.

Answer (score 0):

According to new Android permission model it's impossible. So I can just suggest you 2 hacks how you can at least avoid crashes without significant changes of your app architecture:

1. Set `targetSdkVersion` to 22 as proposed in comments.

OR

2. Add extra `Activity` to your app's starting point, ask all bunch of Permissions there and prevent continuing without granting all of them.

Of course this is not the recommended way, just a possible quick fix which you can use to keep app in working condition until you will implement it according to permission model Best Practices.